# iPhone ad hoc distribution results in wrong orientation

Tags: iphone, orientation, provisioning, adhoc

When I created an ad-hoc provision to test my app remotely, the landscape setting malfunctions.  The app is supposed to be landscape with the home button on the right.  When I create an adhoc provision for one of my devices here, it works fine.  One of my devices a coworker is using remotely, however, shows the app in portrait mode (so the right half is cut off).  I suspected my plist info file wasn't carrying over but that wasn't it as I set the orientation value outright through code and it still didn't work.  I'm a bit befuddled why it breaks on one device and not another.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Update: I noticed that the app actually shows up as "upside down" (home button on top) on his device.  It should be on the right, so something is ... double rotating it? :-/

Comment: Further Update: So I noticed that the initial status bar and pop-up dialogs (like asking to use Location Services) appear in the correct orientation, and that it is only my various displayed UIViews that seem rotated incorrectly.  What I do to run my app in landscape is add a root "rotated" view that everything is a child of, and that view is transformed 90 degrees.  Is there any reason that would choke on one device yet work just fine on others?  The fact that it works on mine and not on the one remote device is what mystifies me the most.

Comment: Another update: I got it to "work" by removing the "Initial Interface Orientation" in my plist.  With it, the bad device was rotating my content as per that setting only on that one device (but not on my others).  So *now*, the bad device is *not* rotating it and my own rots properly place it (as they do for every other device where the Initial Interface Orientation doesn't seem to affect the root of UIViews.  The status bar still starts portrait and system dialogs are in portrait, so it doesn't look nice.

Does anyone know if added views are supposed to be rotated as per that setting or not?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the cause!

Apparently, the misbehaving ipod touch had not been setup for mail.  My app had invoked some in-app email functionality and induced the system dialog asking the user to setup mail.  This in turn caused some trouble that apparently resulted in subviews being automatically rotated to the orientation of the app.  I do not know if this is a problem specific to the foundation code of my engine, but hopefully if this trips up someone in the future, this can help.